# Transform array to column dynamically using pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I'm having a trouble with a json dataframe:

```
{
     "keys":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "start":"2019-05-10",
           "end":"2019-05-11",
           "property":[
              {
                 "key":"home",
                 "value":"1000"
              },
              {
                 "key":"office",
                 "value":"exit"
              },
              {
                 "key":"car",
                 "value":"ford"
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "start":"2019-05-11",
           "end":"2019-05-12",
           "property":[
              {
                 "key":"home",
                 "value":"2000"
              },
              {
                 "key":"office",
                 "value":"out"
              },
              {
                 "key":"car",
                 "value":"fiat"
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }


 root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- start: string (nullable = true)
 |-- end: string (nullable = true)
 |-- property: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to have key and value as column, where key is the name of column and value is the value in the dataframe. 
At first I used `getItem` with an alias,:

```
df.select("id","start","end",col("property.value").getItem(0).alias("home"),col("property.value").getItem(1).alias("office"),col("property.value").getItem(2).alias("car")
```

But elements number and position can change, so i thought to provide a new schema with all the possible value for key, and to set value from my dataframe, without being joined to the position, but i think it is a low performance solution.

I tried also using pivot but i don't have the correct result as shown in figure, in fact i need to have split column, without a comma in the column name and value

```
id |start          |end         |[home, office, car]
+---+--------------+------------+--------------
|1  |2019-05-10    |2019-05-11      |[1000,exit,ford]                                                                            
|2  |2019-05-11    |2019-05-12      |[2000,out,fiat]
```

I need this schema updating dynamically the fields, which number can be fixed:

```
 |-- root
     |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- start: string (nullable = true)
     |-- end: string (nullable = true)
     |-- home: string (nullable = true)
     |-- office: string (nullable = true)
     |-- car: string (nullable = true)
     |-- cycle: string (nullable = true)
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: your json file seems to be corrupted - could you please paste a valid json? It'd be quicker to help.

Comment: ok, thank you. i've updated my json, i had problems pasting it.

Comment: OK, I guess I managed to make it working. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find my try below. I deliberately expanded it into a couple of steps so that you could see how the final df was created (feel free to wrap these steps, however this would not have any impact on the performance).

```
    inputJSON = "/tmp/my_file.json"
    dfJSON = spark.read.json(inputJSON, multiLine=True)
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F



    df = dfJSON.select(F.explode(dfJSON["keys"]).alias("x"))
    df2 = df.select(F.col("x.start").alias("start"),F.col("x.end").alias("end"),F.col("x.id").alias("id"),F.col("x.property").alias("property"))

    df3 = df2.select(F.col("start"),F.col("end"),F.col("id"), F.explode(df2["property"]).alias("properties"))

    df4 = df3.select(F.col("start"),F.col("end"),F.col("id"), F.col("properties.key").alias("key"), F.col("properties.value").alias("value"))

    df4.groupBy("start","end","id").pivot('key').agg(F.last('value', True)).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+---+----+----+------+
|     start|       end| id| car|home|office|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+------+
|2019-05-11|2019-05-12|  2|fiat|2000|   out|
|2019-05-10|2019-05-11|  1|ford|1000|  exit|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+------+
```

Schemas:

```
dfJSON.printSchema()     
        root
         |-- keys: array (nullable = true)
         |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
         |    |    |-- end: string (nullable = true)
         |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
         |    |    |-- property: array (nullable = true)
         |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
         |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
         |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
         |    |    |-- start: string (nullable = true)


df2.printSchema()
    root
     |-- start: string (nullable = true)
     |-- end: string (nullable = true)
     |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- property: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)


df3.printSchema()
    root
     |-- start: string (nullable = true)
     |-- end: string (nullable = true)
     |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)


df4.printSchema()
    root
     |-- start: string (nullable = true)
     |-- end: string (nullable = true)
     |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- key: string (nullable = true)
     |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i tried it but i received an error during the last step(group by and pivot) apparently caused by the alias "properties":   
File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.pivot.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: _gen_alias_38#38
 .......  
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find _gen_alias_38#38 in [properties#18]

Comment: Did you use the same file for testing? It would be strange if it was because of the alias. Maybe something wrong is with the schema - I've added `printSchema` statements in between - please check if the schemas are the same at your end.

Comment: yes, i used the same file. i 've noticed an info log : "INFO aggregate.HashAggregateExec: spark.sql.codegen.aggregate.map.twolevel.enabled is set to true, but current version of codegened fast hashmap does not support this aggregate." , so i've thought to test changing my spark version from 3.0.0 to 2.4.5 and your solution worked perfectly!thank you!

Comment: OK, good to hear! I'd be grateful for marking my solution as accepted or at least thumbs up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`groupBy`** and **`pivot`**.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

cols=['home','office','car']

spark.read.option("multiline","true").\
json("<path>").\
selectExpr("explode(keys)").\
selectExpr("col.id","col.start","col.end","explode(col.property)").\
select("id","start","end","col.*").\
groupBy("id","start","end").\
pivot("key").\
agg(first("value")).\
withColumn("[home,office,car]",array(*cols)).\
drop(*cols).\
show()
#+---+----------+----------+------------------+
#| id|     start|       end| [home,office,car]|
#+---+----------+----------+------------------+
#|  1|2019-05-10|2019-05-11|[1000, exit, ford]|
#|  2|2019-05-11|2019-05-12| [2000, out, fiat]|
#+---+----------+----------+------------------+
```